# C++ removing elements in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to write a Remove_Node function for my code and having issues with removing first and last element. Somehow this code doesn't work. If I remove element in the middle, let's say 3 and then first one, the result is not correct. Also, how to deal with the last element?

```
 void Remove_Node(int ind) {
        LNode *tmp = Root;
        LNode *tmp1;
        if (Root->Next == NULL){
                delete Root;
        }
        else if (ind == 1){
                tmp1 = tmp;
                tmp->tmp.Next;
                delete tmp1;
        }
        else{
                for (int i=1; i<ind-1; i++) tmp = tmp->Next;
                tmp1 = tmp->Next->Next;
                delete tmp->Next;
                tmp->Next = tmp1;
        }
    }
```

};

Comment: You don't ever re-assign root; first index should be 0; tmp->Next->Next is only valid if tmp->Next is not nullptr (which fails for last element), you  need to check.

Comment: And you don't check if index is in range at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `Root` in case of deleting first element

```
else if (ind == 1){
            tmp1 = tmp;
            tmp->tmp.Next;
            delete tmp1;
            Root = tmp;
```

Also you don't ensure if you have at least `ind` nodes.

Comment: @Aconcagua How would I add a validation? I am a bit confused about the algorithm on how to to ensure avoiding nullptr, for example, currently it happens if I choose index outside of the count of elements in the list.

Comment: @Jdreamer Very first check: `if(Root) { /* all the rest */ }`; within your for loop: `if(!tmp) { return; }`; then check equivalently if there is a next element at all *after* the loop (which won't be the case if removing the tail).

Answer (score 0):

See comments in code:

```
void Remove_Node(unsigned int ind)
// (if you use unsigned, you don't have to check for < 0)
{
    LNode* tmp = Root;
    if(!tmp) // check, if the list is empty
    {
        // whatever index, we are out of range...
        // -> some error handling, e. g. throwing an exception:
        throw std::out_of_range("whatever...");
    }
    else if(ind == 0) // first element in list -> need to adjust Root!
    {
        Root = root->Next; // will get nullptr if no further elements
        delete tmp; // delete original root
    }
    else
    {
        //for (int i = 0; i < ind - 1; i++)
        // this is simpler in given case:
        while(--ind)
        {
            if(!tmp->Next) // there is no successor to delete...
                throw std::out_of_range("whatever...");
            tmp = tmp->Next;
        }
        // now tmp points to one node before the one to delete
        LNode* tmp1 = tmp->Next;
        if(!tmp1) // no successor!
            throw std::out_of_range("whatever...");

        tmp->Next = tmp1->Next; // getting nullptr if tmp1 has no successor
        delete tmp1;
    }
}
```

(Code is not checked via IDE/compiler, if you find a bug, feel free to fix it yourself...)